# How to convert hyphen in text feature list to HTML list items using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-1.0

I have an XML file for Real Estate property listings - one of the fields, called 'AdvNotes' contains features of the property. These are usually entered as plain text as follows:

```
Property features:
 - feature one
 - feature two
 - feature three
 - feature four
 - etc
```

I would like to convert the lines into an HTML list, so my output becomes...

```
Property features:
<ul><li>
feature one
</li><li> feature two
</li><li> feature three
</li><li> feature four
</li><li>  etc
</li></ul>
```

Can anyone offer a solution as to how this is accomplished with XSLT ver 1?

Complete XSL file (without the AdvNotes template) is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><!-- DWXMLSource="NewInTown_20110918170305.xml" -->
<!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet  [
    <!ENTITY nbsp   "&#160;">
    <!ENTITY copy   "&#169;">
    <!ENTITY reg    "&#174;">
    <!ENTITY trade  "&#8482;">
    <!ENTITY mdash  "&#8212;">
    <!ENTITY ldquo  "&#8220;">
    <!ENTITY rdquo  "&#8221;"> 
    <!ENTITY pound  "&#163;">
    <!ENTITY yen    "&#165;">
    <!ENTITY euro   "&#8364;">
]>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"/>
<xsl:param name="PropertyID"/>
<xsl:key name="propertylist" match="Properties/Property" use="@PropertyID" />
<xsl:template match="/">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title>REST Property Detail</title>
</head>
<body class="container_12 clearfix">
<xsl:for-each select="key('propertylist',$PropertyID)">
    <h2><xsl:value-of select="StreetNumber"/>&nbsp;<xsl:value-of select="StreetName"/>,&nbsp;<xsl:value-of select="Suburb"/></h2>
    <div class="grid_9">
        <div id="propertySlides">
            <xsl:for-each select="Images/Image">
                <img src="/storage/rest/{@FileName}" title="Image {@ImageID}" alt="Image {@ImageID}" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
        <h3 class="grid_8"><xsl:value-of select="AdvHeading"/></h3>
        <div class="grid_4 alpha" id="AdvDescription"><xsl:value-of select="AdvDescription"/></div>
        <div class="grid_4 omega" id="AdvNotes"><xsl:value-of select="AdvNotes"/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_3">
        <h4 id="propStats"><xsl:value-of select="Features/Bedrooms"/>&nbsp;<img src="/storage/gfx/bed_icon.gif" alt="Bedrooms" width="24" height="16" /> &nbsp; <xsl:value-of select="Features/Bathrooms"/>&nbsp;<img src="/storage/gfx/bath_icon.gif" alt="Bathrooms" width="24" height="16" /> &nbsp; <xsl:value-of select="Features/Garages"/>&nbsp;<img src="/storage/gfx/car_icon.gif" alt="Garages" width="24" height="16" /></h4>
        <div id="gmap">
            <h6>Map Reference: <xsl:value-of select="MapReference"/> (p<xsl:value-of select="MapPage"/>)</h6>
        </div>
        <h6>Available: <xsl:value-of select="DateAvailable"/></h6>
        <h3>$<xsl:value-of select="Rent"/> per week</h3>
        <ul id="propertyFeatures">
            <li id="LandArea"><strong>Land Area</strong>m<sup>2</sup><xsl:value-of select="LandArea"/></li>
            <li><strong>Building Area</strong> <xsl:value-of select="BuildingArea"/>m<sup>2</sup></li>
            <li><strong>Heating</strong> <xsl:value-of select="Features/Heating/@Type"/></li>
            <li><strong>Hot Water</strong> <xsl:value-of select="Features/HotWater/@Type"/></li>
            <li><strong>Laundry</strong> <xsl:value-of select="Features/Laundry/@Type"/></li>
            <xsl:if test="contains(Features/AirConditioning,'1')">
                <li><strong>Air Con</strong> <img src="/storage/gfx/tick.png" alt="Air Conditioning" /></li>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="contains(Features/Ensuite,'1')">
                <li><strong>Ensuite</strong> <img src="/storage/gfx/tick.png" alt="Ensuite" /></li>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="contains(Features/Alarm,'1')">
                <li><strong>Alarm</strong> <img src="/storage/gfx/tick.png" alt="Alarm" /></li>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="contains(Features/Pool,'1')">
                <li><strong>Pool</strong> <img src="/storage/gfx/tick.png" alt="Pool" /></li>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="contains(Features/Spa,'1')">
                <li><strong>Spa</strong> <img src="/storage/gfx/tick.png" alt="" /></li>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="contains(Features/Balcony,'1')">
                <li><strong>Balcony</strong> <img src="/storage/gfx/tick.png" alt="Balcony" /></li>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="contains(Features/BuildingSecurity,'1')">
                <li><strong>Security</strong> <img src="/storage/gfx/tick.png" alt="Building Security" /></li>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="contains(Features/NearShops,'1')">
                <li><strong>Near Shops</strong> <img src="/storage/gfx/tick.png" alt="Near Shops" /></li>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="contains(Features/NearTransport,'1')">
                <li><strong>Near Transport</strong> <img src="/storage/gfx/tick.png" alt="Near Transport" /></li>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="contains(Features/NearBeach,'1')">
                <li><strong>Near Beach</strong> <img src="/storage/gfx/tick.png" alt="Near Beach" /></li>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="contains(Features/CityViews,'1')">
                <li><strong>City Views</strong> <img src="/storage/gfx/tick.png" alt="City Views" /></li>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="contains(Features/WaterViews,'1')">
                <li><strong>River Views</strong> <img src="/storage/gfx/tick.png" alt="River Views" /></li>
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="contains(Features/Intercom,'1')">
                <li id="Intercom"><strong>Intercom</strong> <img src="/storage/gfx/tick.png" alt="xxxx" /></li>
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="contains(Features/Vacuum,'1')">
                <li id="Vacuum"><strong>Vacuum</strong> <img src="/storage/gfx/tick.png" alt="Vacuum" /></li>
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="contains(Features/FirePlace,'1')">
                <li id="Fireplace"><strong>Fireplace</strong> <img src="/storage/gfx/tick.png" alt="FirePlace" /></li>
            </xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="contains(Features/Furnished,'1')">
            <li id="Furnished"><strong>Furnished</strong> <img src="/storage/gfx/tick.png" alt="Furnished" /></li>
            </xsl:if>

            <li style="clear:both;"></li>
        </ul>
        <h3><strong>Interested?</strong></h3>
        <p>Contact the property agent directly or <a href="/contact/">make an enquiry here</a>.</p>
        <h4><a><xsl:attribute name="href">mailto:<xsl:value-of select="/Contacts/Contact/Email" />?subject=<xsl:value-of select="StreetNumber" />&nbsp;<xsl:value-of select="StreetName" />&nbsp;<xsl:value-of select="Suburb" /></xsl:attribute>Agent Name</a><br />
            mobile</h4>
        <p>Phone: BHphone<br />
            After hours: AHphone</p>


    </div>
</xsl:for-each>

<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#propertySlides').innerfade({
        speed: 'slow',
        timeout: 5000,
        type: 'sequence',
        containerheight: '420px'
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'd be happy to look at a solution for XSLT version 1 or 2.

Comment: empo gave you as a good a solution as can be done with XSLT, but it has to be added that it's really not the right way to be doing these things. Pretty much any language would be a more natural choice, and much easier. XSLT is designed for transforming data that is already XML; if you like the functional approach of parsing some funny text format, process it using Haskell or something; otherwise plain C, or any language of your choice, can grab lines from a file and manipulate them more idiomatically than writing a long splurge of XSLT.

Comment: My client uses a tool designed for the real estate industry that spits out a ZIP package containing an XML file and up to 9 images per property. The goal is for my client to be able to upload this to the server and be done with it - the client won't be able to do anything more than this.

Currently we have it working beautifully, but the Feature List comes out as one long text string - I tried a jQuery find/replace plugin to replace hyphens but it didn't work and I presume this is because the XML data isn't returned as part of the page DOM?

I'll try empo's solution and report back later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This to get you started. Things can become much more complicated if the hyphen may appear also inside a list item.

---

XSLT 2.0 (split by tokenize)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="AdvNotes">
        <xsl:variable name="tokens" select="tokenize(.,'-')"/>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="$tokens[1]"/>
        </p>
        <ul>
            <xsl:for-each select="remove($tokens,1)">
                <li>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </li>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

XSLT 1.0 (split by recursion)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="AdvNotes">
        <xsl:variable name="p" select="substring-before(.,'-')"/>
        <p>
            <xsl:value-of select="$p"/>
        </p>
        <ul>
            <xsl:call-template name="to_list"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="to_list">
        <xsl:param name="li" select="substring-after(.,'-')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="item" select="substring-before($li,'-')"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="not($item)">
                <li>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$li"/>
                </li>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <li>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$item"/>
                </li>   
                <xsl:call-template name="to_list">
                 <xsl:with-param name="li" select="substring-after($li,'-')"/>
                </xsl:call-template> 
            </xsl:otherwise> 
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Both transformations produce:

```
<p>
Property features:
 </p>
<ul>
   <li> feature one
 </li>
   <li> feature two
 </li>
   <li> feature three
 </li>
   <li> feature four
 </li>
   <li> etc
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: empo, this looks ideal - I'll try this implementation and report back. Thanks for your time.

Comment: This code works fine as is, but I can't seem to get this to working when I add it into my own XSL file - I'm not familiar with templating in XSL and so am guessing my structure is all wrong? I'll update the original question with my complete XSL - if you can spare the time, I would really appreciate an explanation as to where/how to integrate this code.

Comment: Please provide input sample and wanted output if possible.

Comment: The XML file is here:
http://www.newintown.net.au/storage/rest/NewInTown_20110918170305.xml
The example page is here:
http://newintown.net.au/rest-detail?PropertyID=31
See the middle column (Other features include:) - note that the client has switched from hyphens to using commas to delimit each feature.

Comment: In your XSL file you are using a single template. To integrate my own you should insert `xsl:apply-templates select="AdvNotes"` in your template, in the place you want the list to be generated, at the level of **property** element.